# Can I install MiKTeX 2.9 on my Windows XP Service Pack 2 system?

Tags: miktex, installing, windows

I'm using an Pentium 4 desktop PC, with an Intel Celeron 1,8 GHz processor, 1 GB of RAM, and 40 GB of hard disk space, partitioned into C:, D:, and E: drives.

I'm running Microsodt Windows XP Service Pack 2 on my computer.

I'm trying to install the MiKTeX 2.9.5823, which is available for download from the following URL:

http://miktex.org/download

However, when I visited the page with the URL

http://miktex.org/kb/prerequisites,

I noticed that amongst the required versions of Windows, there is no mention of Windows XP Service Pack 2.

Although Windows XP Service Pack 3 is one of the operating systems supported, I'm not so comfortable upgrading to Service Pack 3 because doing so has resulted in other problems, e.g., the HTML help files not showing any contents in the right pane.

MiKTeX 2.8 has reached the "end of life" status, as is mentioned on the following pages:

http://miktex.org/2.8/setup

http://miktex.org/2.8/status

What are my options?

Comment: You should be able to install. On a completely different and off-topic note: Windows XP has reached its end of life status as well.

Comment: I've installed TeXLive 2015 on a Windows XP computer (for testing only!) -- it runs without problems, I assume, that `MikTeX` will do so too

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I can of course switch to TexLive, or any other system, but will I be able to access my .tex files that I've created using MikeTex and WinEdit using those other systems? Will it not be cause any issues accessing and editting the contents of those files?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud: I did not say that you should switch to TL. And of course you will be able to use your own files -- I do hope you did not store them in the MikTeX tree, of course. MikTeX gets the packages from CTAN as does TeXLive.

Comment: @Johannes_B you're right, and I would certainly like to upgrade to Windows 7, but my PC can't handle Windows 7, I'm afraid. It's just too limited in terms of resources. I've been using this computer since April 2004!

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud: I hope your CMOS battery is still alife for a while ;-)

Comment: You tex files are text (note the extra t) that you can edit with any text editor, even notepad. You wont have any problems editing your files. TeX Live is a tiny bit more restrictive with respect to licenses, so a few packages less. But AFAIR all those that are missing aren't really doing anything useful.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, you never said I should migrate to some other system. But I would have no problem doing so provided that doing so will not result in my getting locked out of the .tex files that I've created using MikeTex, which I've stored on my D: drive, or in directories other than those where MikeTex installs.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer please note that I'm using Windows XP Service Pack 2. And, the 2.9.5823 relaese of MikeTex does work on Windows XP Service pack 3, as the prerequisite page of the site states.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud: Well, as I wrote -- keep your personal `.tex` files in a private folder or another partition and all should be well. I think I have Service Pack 2 XP on the other machine and TL 2015 runs.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that's exactly what I usually do. But will ProText work on Windows XP SP2? And, can you please send me the exact link for downloading it? I've been able to find this page. https://tug.org/protext/

Comment: I have no idea if miktex will work on such a system as I no longer have a win xp. But I wouldn't use protext to install it. Protext installs more components and so the probability that something doesn't work is higher.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud: ProTexT? Never heard of it

Comment: @UlrikeFischer then what do you recommend? ProText is the version for Windows of TexLive. Please visit the following page. https://tug.org/protext/

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ProText is the version for Windows of TexLive. Please visit the following page. https://tug.org/protext/

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud: Actually, according to that site, ProTeXt is somewhat a MikTeX clone, but not related to TeXLive. TL for Windows is available here: http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-windows.exe

Comment: I would install either a native miktex (http://www.miktex.org/download) or a native texlive (https://www.tug.org/texlive/). If it works you can then install an editor like winedt separatly. (btw: protext is based on miktex, not on texlive).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is it Ok to download and install the file at the following link? http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-windows.exe

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've run the installation of TexLive and have encountered following issue during the extraction process: Output folder: C:\DOCUME~1\Crowe\LOCALS~1\Temp\nsk18.tmp
Create folder: C:\DOCUME~1\Crowe\LOCALS~1\Temp\nsk18.tmp\install-tl-20151218
Output folder: C:\DOCUME~1\Crowe\LOCALS~1\Temp\nsk18.tmp\install-tl-20151218
... 
Can't spawn "C:\DOCUME~1\Crowe\LOCALS~1\Temp\nsk18.tmp\install-tl-20151218\tlpkg\installer\wget\wget.exe": Inappropriate I/O control operation at C:/DOCUME~1/Crowe/LOCALS~1/Temp/nsk18.tmp/install-tl-20151218/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2665.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with specific installation questions. I don't have such an old system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for your helpful comments. I've managed to install MikeTex 2.9.5823 successfully! Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op solved the problem (see comment) without telling how ...

Comment: The fact the OP did solve the problem doesn't prevent the question to benefit the site or other people - like me - that arrive here with a very similar problem. I wouldn't have closed the question.