# TeXnicCenter in Wine on Linux

Tags: miktex, texlive, linux, texniccenter

I worked with TeXstudio and TeXmaker on Linux several years, but still I prefer TeXnicCenter. (f.e. there is a easy to change the compileroption from pdflatex to dvilatex&dvi2ps&ps2pdf and back)

I tried Kile, but it does not work properly on Networkdrives (sftp://)

I installed TeXnicCenter, by just running downloading the executable save it and open it:

```
chmod a+x TXCSetup_2.02Stable_x64.exe
./TXCSetup_2.02Stable_x64.exe
```

Then the configuration Wizard of TeXnicCenter asks:
"Enter the full path of the directory, where the executables (latex, tex, etc.) of your TeX-distribution are located:"
[image: path of tex-directory]

- I have texlive installed on Ubuntu 16.04 can I use this installation? What's the path I have to specify?
- or do I have to install MikTeX in Wine? (There should also be TexLive for Windows?) MikTeX now offers also a version for Linux, but in Wine I have to use the Windows-Installer one?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `which pdflatex` to see the path of your current tex distribution. Then just try if it works with texniccenter.

Comment: Is texniccenter even supported any more? Last release is from 2013, I'd probably not waste too much time on it.

Comment: @samcarter:
I tried `which pdflatex` and `which latex` both gave me `/usr/bin/latex` (or `/usr/bin/pdflatex`)

I tried to spezify `Z:\usr\bin` but it said 
"The application 'LaTeX' has not been found in the directory of your TeX-distribution.

Please enter the directory where the executables files (tex.exe, latex.exe, etc.) are located, as your distribution's directory."
@daleif The Grafical userinterface does not need to be updated, the packages regularly.

Comment: @JoKalliauer Why do you add the `Z:` if the programs are in `/usr/bin/`?

Comment: @samcarter: I used the `...` opion and searched for the path (grafically) it automatically saved it as `Z:\usr\bin`

neither `/usr/bin/` nor `Z:\usr\bin` works.

Comment: I'd say, you are going the wrong way. If you need to use remote files, solve this issue, e.g by mounting the remote resource locally. Look out for curlftpfs, sshfs, smb4k and probably some more. There are more LaTeX Editors than Kile, but I used Kile as standard, before I learned about the difference to a real editor. Emacs.

Comment: @KeksDose I am using TeXstudio (sometimes TeXmaker) on a dayly basis, but still I prefer TeXnicCenter. (How it displays the log-file, how the window is organized by default, the default configuration of the toolboxes) I have to change several times between pdflatex and dvilatex&dvi2ps&ps2pdf. In TeXstudio (define a keycombination) and Texmaker (change the default compiler in the options) it is quite unhandy.

Comment: @JoKalliauer Give kile a second chance. I switched between pdflatex and latex with a shortcut when using kile.

Comment: You have to mount a network drive not with kile, but using the linux OS. Google »sftp mount ubuntu«, e.g. see here: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/FUSE/sshfs/ (site in German). From kile it is just opening a local address, e.g. /mnt/serversite/file.tex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing MikTeX is problematic (but @saaqib-mahmuud somhow managed it on Windows XP (very simmilar to wine) see comments of
[Can I install MikeTex 2.9 on my Windows XP Service Pack 2 system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283908/can-i-install-miketex-2-9-on-my-windows-xp-service-pack-2-system#comment684947_283908) )

Therefore I installed texlive ([tug.org/texlive](http://tug.org/texlive/)), direct link:
http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-windows.exe

The path in TeXnicCenter for latex is `C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\` (which is actually stored in `~/.wine/drive_c/texlive/2017/bin/win32`)